# Navigation issue undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

Hey guys I'm having an issue with navigation:

- I select an item from the menuoption
- I then call the 'testFunction'
- Function will call an alert function so it is working
- When I add the navigation part I get the error below:

  undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

[image]

Here is the import code:

```
import { NavigationScreenProp } from "react-navigation";
```

Here is where it is added to props:

```
interface NotificationDropdownProps {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any,any>
}
```

Here is where code is rendered:

```
 class NotificationDropdown extends React.Component<Props, NotificationDropdownState> {

 testFunction = () => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Leagues')
              };
    
            <MenuOption 
            
            onSelect={() => 
                {
                    if(notification.type == INotificationType.SYSTEM){
                        this.testFunction()
                    }
                }   
            }
             customStyles={{ optionWrapper: { padding: 0, margin: 0, zIndex: 100000000 } }}>
                <View style={[styles.notificationContainer]}  >
                    <View style={styles.iconArea}>
                        <View style={[styles.iconCircle]}>
                            <Icon name={this.getIconType(notification.type)}
                                color={this.notificationColor(notification.type)} size={26} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
    
                    <View style={styles.notificationData} >
                        <Text style={styles.notificationTxt}>{notification.text}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.notificationDate}>{this.getDate(new Date(notification.dateCreated))}</Text>
                    </View>
    
                </View>
            </MenuOption>
```

Render:

```
render() {
        return (
            <Menu
                renderer={Popover} rendererProps={{ placement: 'bottom', preferredPlacement: 'bottom' }}
                opened={this.state.opened}
                onBackdropPress={() => this.togglePopup()}
                onClose={() => {
                    this.setState({ showEmpty: true });
                    // Store.dispatch(SetNotificationSeen());
                }}
                onOpen={() => {
                    Store.dispatch(SetNumberSeen(this.props.notifications.length));
                }}
            >
                <MenuTrigger onPress={() => this.togglePopup()}>
                    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                        <Icon name='ios-notifications-outline' color={'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'} size={25} /></View>
                </MenuTrigger>

                <MenuOptions customStyles={{
                    optionsContainer: {
                        width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.75,
                        zIndex: 100000000,
                        elevation: 8,
                        borderRadius: 20
                    }
                }}>

                    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                        <Text style={{
                            fontSize: 20,
                            marginLeft: 10,
                            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            paddingBottom: 5
                            
                        
                        }}>Notifications</Text>

                        {this.props.notifications.length > 0 ? <FlatList
                            contentContainerStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
                            // only allow 5 notifications
                            data={this.props.notifications.slice(0,5)}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderNotification(item)}
                            style={{ maxHeight: 200, zIndex: 5 }}
                            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        /> : <Text style={styles.noNotifications}>No Notifications!</Text>}

                    </View>
                </MenuOptions>
            </Menu>
        );
    }
```

What am I missing? any help is welcome

Here is where the  is called from the header.tsx

```
<View style={styles.icon}>
                        <NotificationDropdown />
                        {this.props.numberSeen < this.props.notificationCount ? <Badge value={this.props.notificationCount - this.props.numberSeen > 99 ? '99+' : this.props.notificationCount - this.props.numberSeen}
                            status="error" containerStyle={styles.badge} /> : null}
                    </View>
```

Comment: Can you display all the NavigationDropDown file please.

Comment: I've added more context there, notice anything wrong?\

Comment: It should work. Can I see where you use please `<NavigationDropDown />`

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean (very new to this)

Comment: I know I'm making a silly mistake somewhere

Comment: Somewhere in your app, you use this component or not?

Comment: Show me the file where you use this component please

Comment: Ive added where I call it in the headercomponent.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems that `NavigationDropDown` doesn't have the `navigation` props.

What you need is to pass the navigation props explicitly as it is not a screen component.

in the headercomponent.tsx

```
<View style={styles.icon}>
                        <NotificationDropdown navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                        {this.props.numberSeen < this.props.notificationCount ? <Badge value={this.props.notificationCount - this.props.numberSeen > 99 ? '99+' : this.props.notificationCount - this.props.numberSeen}
                            status="error" containerStyle={styles.badge} /> : null}
                    </View>
```

I assume that you have the navigation props in the `headercomponent.tsx`

Comment: Thank you!! How do I add navigation props ?

Comment: You don't have the navigation props in `headercomponent.tsx`?